# return textfield keyboard on editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I am working on iphone application in which i have to return the keyboard when i edit my textfield or delete the text in textfield also my textfield should allow only one character in textfield.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and implement the following method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

You can get the length of the text in the textfield. If it is greater than 1, then, resign the first responder.

You can do something like this, considering `_textField` as your textfield object.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if( textField == _textField )
    {
        if( [textField.text length] == 0 )
        {        
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```